# Why does Mathematica 10 autocomplete not work with \[Breve]?

Tags: version-10, autocomplete

Let us define the following symbol:

```
v˘name
```

(The Brave (˘) is typed by entering [EscapeKey]bv[EscapeKey].)

In Mathematica 9, this symbol name is shown as a proposal by autocomplete as soon as I enter the third character ‘n’.

In Mathematica 10 this seems not to work anymore.

Does anybody know how to fix this?